# Scala: Initialization of var in class

Tags: scala

I am beginner of Scala, I try to make a class and use of it, which class has variables (**var**) and some processing (in **def**). I write class like as follows;

```
class Example() {
    var ExampleVar0 = 0
    var ExampleVar1 = 0

    def ExampleProcessing(_arg0: Int, _arg1: Int) : (Int, Int) = {
        ExampleVar0 = _arg0 + 1
        ExampleVar1 = _arg1 - 1
        (ExampleVar0*2, ExampleVar1/2)
    }
}
```

I want to initialize `ExampleVar*` and to keep and update the value. I use the class in other class;

```
var result0
var result1
val exp = Example()
exp.ExampleProcessing(5, 6)(result0, result1)
```

The both of result0 and result1 is zero, seems always write with zero by statement of the `var ExampleVar0 = 0`. I checked the value of the var (`println(exp.ExampleVar0.toString)`) then it is always zero. I might misunderstand about initialization of var.

Could you please point out where is my misunderstand and how to solve it?

Comment: They are primitive types, and you are invoking a method, the results of the method need to be assigned back to the variables. It won't mutate unless and until you are updating a reference.
`val (newResult0 , newResult1) = exp.ExampleProcessing(5, 6)(result0, result1)`

Comment: You never assign to `result0` or `result1`, so they will always have the default value.

Comment: Using public/class level `var` is a bad practice in Scala

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using `result0` and `result1` as method parameters, which does not look right. Try this:

```
val exp = Example()
val (result0, result1) = exp.ExampleProcessing(5, 6)
```

In this case the `var` does not seem to be relevant or necessary, but I will give the usual warning that it is best to avoid `var` and use immutable data structures.